# Sending HTTP Requests Through Azure

Tags: javascript, http, azure, xmlhttprequest, azure-storage

I am trying to interact with Urbanairship via their broadcast API to send notifications to android devices on an INSERT into a Azure table.

My JavaScript INSERT code on Azure is as follows:

```
    function insert(item, user, request) {

        request.execute({
            success: function() {
                request.respond(statusCodes.OK, item.id);
                push();
            }
        });
    }

    function push() {
   var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var authen = 'UDQ3N...B'
    var url = "https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/broadcast/";
    var data = '{ "android": { "alert": "Hello from Azure!"} }';

    client.open("POST", url, true);
    client.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Basic ' + authen); 
    client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    client.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', '54');
    client.send(data);
}
```

However I get no responses from Urbanairship. I am convinced its an issue with Azure because using fiddler the following HTTP Request works:

```
POST https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/broadcast/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Authorization: Basic UDQ3N...B
Content-Type: application/json
Host: go.urbanairship.com
Content-Length: 54

{ "android": { "alert": "Hello from Urban Airship!"} }
```

So in essence, I am trying to repeat this call with JavaScript through Azure but having no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you not getting any HTTP response (you should get a 400 if the request is received but not processed) or just not getting a notification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a Windows Azure tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj631641.aspx